# Xcode doesn't stop execution on assertion failure when debugging Unity Editor

Tags: xcode, macos, unity-game-engine, objective-c++

I'm currently working on native plugin for Unity Engine. So there's my custom c++/objective-c++ code running inside Unity Editor process. Breakpoints are working just fine, but when assertion failure happens Editor just crashes and Xcode says `Finished running Unity` instead of stopping debugger.

I have 2 cases when there may be assertion failure:

1. Assertion in my own c++/objective-c++ code.
2. Xcode validation (e.g. Metal API Validation)

In both cases Editor just crashes, Xcode says `Finished running Unity`, then Unity Crash Reporter appears, and finally macOS crash reported appears.

To start Unity Editor from Xcode I followed this guide: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/XcodeFrameDebuggerIntegration.html (`Capturing a frame from Unity Editor with Xcode` section)

How can I make Xcode/Unity Editor stop execution and show line/assertion info when assertion failure happens?

Answer (score 1):

This is a design "feature" in Xcode. I noticed such behavior in C++ and it is similar for Obj-C++.

You need to manually add an Exception Breakpoint. See here - [How to add Exception Breakpoint in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/how-to-add-exception-breakpoint-in-xcode)

Enable the **Exception Breakpoint**. **Exception - All**. **Break on - Throw**.

I would also recommend enabling all the memory breakpoints. See here - https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html

Comment: That's not it, I tried enabling them before asking this question. For some reason it doesn't work.

Comment: Under Product -> Edit Scheme -> Info - have you set Debug ?

Comment: Also check under Build Settings -> Generate Debug Symbols. Should be Yes for Debug. I'm sure you got this, but check just in case.

Comment: Yeah, I build debug configuration and it have generate debug symbols enabled. Otherwise breakpoints wouldn't work.